# Generating Username suggestions for user in php

Tags: php

I am implementing a web application using some `html5` and `php` in which user will register. when user is choosing a username, if it exists i want to give him some suggestions. how can i give username suggestions to user.

Thanks

Comment: Come up with stuff based on fields they filled out in their "profile." Append their desired username with their birth year for example (e.g. "sjagr is not available, but sjagr1982 is!")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way THEY do it is by considering the FIRST NAME and LAST NAME that a user enters, also sometimes the birthdate etc. After considering the FN and LN their code searches closest UNUSED username. Say like FN.LN, LN.FN, FNLNbirthdate or FNRandomnumber.

Obviously you'll have to CODE or copy code from somewhere as to what exactly your Application would suggest the username as.

You will have to code for this using AJAX

If any problems still i would be glad to help :)